# Configure error page for @PathVariable type mismatch

Tags: java, spring, servlets, custom-error-pages

Suppose I have a controller:

```
@Controller

public class SomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}/object.do")
    public String showObject(@PathVariable("id") Integer id,
                            HttpServletRequest request) {
            //do smth
            return "somePage";
        }
}
```

When "id" is not a Number, but string like "aaa/object.do" Tomcat show me an error - "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect."

Is there a way to configure an error page that will be shown only when "id" path variable has incorrect type?

Answer (score 4):

You can handle this with [@ExceptionHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler) for this particular error (I suspect it is [TypeMismatchException](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/TypeMismatchException.html))

```
@ExceptionHandler(TypeMismatchException.class)
public ModelAndView handleTypeMismatchException(TypeMismatchException ex) {
    //TODO log
    // Return something reasonable to the end user.
    ...
}
```

Please note, that `@ExceptionHandler` basically has almost the same capabilities, as usual handlers:

> Much like standard controller methods annotated with a @RequestMapping annotation, the method arguments and return values of @ExceptionHandler methods are very flexible.

Comment: Very old post that I like. Do ypu happen to know how to pass dynamic messages to the @ExceptionHandler? For example the default is (for this particular case), "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"k\"". How do I make it: "Please use a number greater than zero" for this case, but "Please use a letter" for another case?